# How to Integrate JWplayer in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, jwplayer, angular2-directives

I'm new to angular2.I want to use to  jw player in my application.I'm unable to understand how to integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly import `jwplayer.js` in `.angular-cli.json`

After that you have to make it visible in your Angular project by adding a type definition:

```
declare var jwplayer: any;
```

You can add this type definition either in the component ts-file or in the `typings.d.ts` file.

Then add the `div` to your component like that:

```
<div id="myDiv">This text will be replaced with a player.</div>
```

Then in the component add the code e.g. in the `ngOnInit` function:

```
jwplayer("myDiv").setup({
"file": "http://example.com/myVideo.mp4",
"image": "http://example.com/myImage.png",
"height": 360,
"width": 640
"key":"yourjwplayerkeyhere"

});
```

Comment: "key":"yourjwplayerkeyhere" is not working. What can be done in this case? The only way it worked for me is to add jwplayer.js reference under index.html and add jwplayer.key also there. But this is a security risk. How to overcome?